# Converting string[] to char**

Tags: d

Suppose I want to forward a set of command line options to a C function, declared as follows, with the D main taking args

```
extern (C) void init(int argc, char** argv);

void main(string[] args) {
    init(args.length, map!(toStringz)(args));
}
```

The first parameter is easy enough, but my attempt at applying `toStringz` to the `args` array doesn't seem to work. I get `cannot implicitly convert expression (map(args)) of type MapResult!(toStringz,string[]) to char**`. How do you convert `string[]` to `char**` (or even `const(char)**`).

Comment: In the next release you'll be able to use `Core.runtime.cArgs` and directly pass its `argc` and `argv` fields to a C function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std.algorithm.map` function returns range, which in your case must be changed into array. You can do this using [`std.array.array`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_array.html#array). Then you can get array pointer using `.ptr`. It returns `immutable(char**)` which is casted into `char**`:

```
extern (C) void init(int argc, char** argv);

void main(string[] args) {
    init(cast(int)args.length, cast(char**)map!(toStringz)(args).array.ptr);
}
```

Here's live demo: http://dpaste.dzfl.pl/ff81984c

Comment: Thanks, works great. Turns out you don't need the `cast(int)` though.

Comment: Because `args.length` is of type `size_t`.

Comment: Without casting `args.length` to `int`, it won't compile on 64-bit machines. It only works on 32-bit machines, because `size_t` is `uint` on 32-bit machines (while it's `ulong` on 64-bit machines).

Comment: Casting away immutable is probably a bad choice, probably should .dup or change C signature to const.

Comment: I guess that the C's `init` signature should be updated to `size_t`.